# Python in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, консоль, ubuntu

Hi, i create empty python file:

```
def main(x,y):
    if x == y:
        print "Ok"
    else:
        print "Error"

main(3,3)
```

on the my desktop, later i run terminal and write command

```
python test.py
```

**Error: no such file or directory**

why!!!???

Comment: > Empty pyhon file

XD, your file contains the code. So, **it's not empty**.

Comment: @John234, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.  
@John234, send your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/).  
Izvinite, za moj anglijskij.

Comment: @ReinRaus, помоему, последнюю строку *ТС* не понял XD

Comment: так я не понял, мне на каком языке отвечать? :)

Comment: @ReinRaus question может быть?

Comment: тонкий аглицкий юмор?

Comment: @rasmisha верно :) такой вот мой английский :)

Comment: @niki-timofe, что-то мне подсказывает, что на фоне несоблюдения временных форм глаголов в данном повествовании, пользователь прекрасно понимает все.

Comment: @Dex, это ни о чем не говорит. Возможно у него какой-нибудь фарси родной, а в русском он совсем слаб.

Comment: Тогда, переводчик Google, *но всё же, я не стал бы на StackOverflow задавать вопросы на Русском...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you run terminal from your **`home path`**.

---

Type

```
cd ~/desktop
```